# Variable Scope Doesn't Make Sense

Tags: variables, vbscript, scope

I have this code, as a part of my program:

```
Dim Txt, st, i, k
i=0 
Do
    st="Example"
    Txt = myReplace(Txt, st, arr(k,i))
    i=i+1
Loop While i<=UBound(arr,2)
```

`arr` is also created before.

For some reason, `Txt` is being reset outside of the loop.
Other variables aren't, for example `st` does show "example".

Can anyone help pls?
Thank you

Edit: We made some progress. At the moment, `Ubound(arr,2)` is worth 2.
If we write `i<=2` it works, although `i<=Ubound(arr,2)` doesn't work.

Comment: The information you provided is insufficient for reproducing the problem. Please [update](http://sscce.org/) your question.

Comment: You should at least publish the code of myReplace(), the initialization of Txt, and - most important - what you want to achieve/expected output.

Answer (score 0):

As you don't provide much information, all I can do is guess.

Maybe you are changing `Txt` inside your `myReplace` function? By default, VBScript passes variables by reference, so functions *can* change the contents of their arguments. I know this was unintuitive to me when I first encountered it...